# Set the position of the caret in an input to the top left

Tags: html, css, web

I'm doing a webpage with full of forms for a class project, so I have this line of code:

```html
<style>
  input {
    text-align: right;
  }
</style>
<form class="input">
  <input style=" text-align: left; padding: 370px 200px; margin-left: 1110px; position: absolute; margin-top: -600px; width: 20%;" type="tel" id="telefono" name="telefono" ><br>
</form>
```

What i really want its to put the cursor at the left top corner

[image]

instead in the center like in the image i want it like this:

[image]

I've tried a lot of things such as putting in the style:

```html
<style>
  input {
    text-align: right;
    direction: ltr;
  }
</style>
```

or just visiting websites such us w3schools or stackoverflow as well.

Pd: if i need javascript for this I don't know how to use it because right now in class teachers didn't taught us, that's for next year.

Comment: @rx2347 the field is for phone number, I don't think it's intended to be a `textarea`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the value you used for padding. You see, your input has the following inline style `padding: 370px 200px` which adds 370px on the vertical axis and 200px on the horizontal access.

Set this value to something smaller (zero or 10px) and it will work as you want.

I strongly recommend you familiarize yourself with the [Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) to understand how this work